# Encrypt data transfer in ruby socket

Tags: ruby, encryption, rsa

some time ago I coded a TCP server to run some services across my PCs and today I decided to implement encryption. My idea was that the server would send his RSA public key, the client would generate an AES key and sent it to the server encrypted with the public key

I use OpenSSL's methods `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)` and `OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)`

The data I transfer is basically an hash with some info, that i turn to json with `{}.to_json`

The error occurs when the server receives the AES key and IV (initialization vector) and tries to decrypt them using `rsaobj.private_decrypt` (the same object from where I took the public key before). I get a "padding check failed error"

I know the way I do all of this is terrible, so if someone could be so kind to explain me another way I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to use OpenSSL for ... SSL connections.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but how could I implement it both on server side and client side?